# Building with CMake

Tags: opencv, cmake, clion

I am building a fairly large project with multiple headers and sources with CLion, which uses CMake as the build system. It is an OpenCV project, and I have specified the include, libs, target_link...everything. It even compiles every source file and generates the object files.

But when it goes to the linking phase, it throws up 'undefined reference to' errors that points to absolutely EVERY OpenCV library function used in the project which numbers in the hundreds. Help with this quandary would be most appreciated.

Sincerely,
gratefulguest.

Comment: You have specified something wrong in your link step.  We can't help further on such limited information.

Comment: Would the error list be enough?

Comment: No.  What you need is the smallest sample that reproduces the problem.  Try making a sample source file that calls one OpenCV function, with no other dependencies, and as simple a CMakeLists.txt as possible to build it.  This will either reproduce the error or not, and either way it's helpful.  This process is as much to help you debug your own code as it is to produce something for others to help you.